# Popup for inherited models of ManyToManyField target

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have apps and models similar to these:

In App 'Animals':

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Lion(Animal):
    roar_loudness_decibel = models.IntegerField()

class Bear(Animal):
    salmons_eaten = models.IntegerField()

# And many more that inherit Animal
```

In Application Zoo:

```
from Animal.models import Animal

class Zoo(models.Model):
    animals = models.ManyToManyField(Animal)
```

In the Django admin interface, I have registered all app models.

Whenever I create a `Zoo` and want to add `animals` in the same form (click the green plus button and get a popup), I get the create form for `Animal` (not the models which have subclassed it).

---

**Is there any way to be able to select which subclassed model to add for a ManyToManyField?**

Or is there a better way to solve this (contenttypes? override the form?)

I'd rather not change the models if I can avoid it.

(I know that it is possible to add `Bear` or `Lion` separately and just select those objects when selecting `animals` for a `Zoo`, but what I'm asking for seems better usability-wise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should've spent more time Googling for this.

I found https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org which offers selecting the child model in the admin interface and much more:

From the docs:

> - The add screen gains an additional step where the desired child model
>     is selected.
> - The edit screen displays the admin interface of the
>     child model.

Answer (score 0):

Override `add_view()` method of the `AnimalAdmin` and if it is called from popup window then show intermediate page with a list of available species.

Just the proof of concept:

**admin.py**

```
class AnimalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):

        if request.method == 'GET' and '_popup' in request.GET:
            return render(request, 'admin/animals/choose_animal.html')

        return super(AnimalAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url,
                                                 extra_context)
```

**templates/admin/animals/choose_animal.html**

```
<body>

    Choose an animal:

    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'admin:app_lion_add' %}?_popup=1">Lion</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'admin:app_bear_add' %}?_popup=1">Bear</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: This would work. I searched a bit more and found a more comprehensive solution: https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org